# Howto create a Bootstrap 3 navbar, whose entire.navbar-header is clickable on iOS 6/7?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I took the vanilla Bootstrap3 Navbar Example: (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) and threw here: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/UFoRIYex/727/edit)

The one edit I made was to move the

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
```

from the ***button.navbar-toggle*** to the ***div.navbar-header***

The resulting div.navbar-header then looks like:

```
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>
```

This has been working great on chrome/firefox, though I haven't tried any IE testing yet, but the desktop versions of it working don't really matter much, since the whole point is the navbar-header only gets shown on mobile devices. It works fine on my Android 4.4.2/Chrome 34.

The problem I'm running into, is *only* the anchor tag (*a.navbar-brand*), and the button (*button.nav-bar-toggle*) are actually clickable on iOS (I tested on iOS 6.1 and 7.1).

[image: iOS Screenshot]

Is there a more clever/reliable way to make the entire ***div.navbar-header*** clickable?

***Edit*** This appears to be an iOS bug, and a work-around was simply to add "cursor: pointer" to the ***div.navbar-header***  I have a full answer/example below.

Comment: Why do you want the entire nav bar clickable? (just wondering)

Comment: To make it easier to toggle, I like having elements that don't require the user to think about where they have to click to get it to work.

Comment: So you want it so when the click the ENTIRE topbar it opens the menu?

Comment: Yup, works great on Chrome/FF, just not working on iOS (Haven't tried IE yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a jQuery bug report that had the missing work-around for this iOS problem: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5677

Adding the ***style="cursor:pointer"*** to the div.navbar-header fixes the onClick event issue.

The resulting code looks like:

```
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="cursor:pointer">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>
```

Here's an updated JSBin: [Working JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/UFoRIYex/729/edit)